# Effect of temperature on battery charging

Tags: batteries, charging

What is the effect of using a temperature-sensor when charging 12-volt batteries?

I have a motorhome with two large 12-volt gel-batteries (plus a 12-volt starter-battery for the car engine), and I am thinking about upgrading the solar-system.

Is it worth it getting a temperature-sensor for the solar charge-controller, or is it somewhat of a gimmick so they can make some extra money on selling the sensor? Because the temperature sensor is surprisingly expensive.

Can the effect of the temperature-sensor be estimated as e.g. a 5% increase in battery-life or something like that? Or is the effect negligible in normal operating temperatures?

Thanks!

Comment: Define 'normal' operating temperatures.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I thought I might get that comment :-) In my case a "normal" temperature range is probably between 10-30 C depending on the time of year. But sometimes I can experience this entire range in a single day! Ideally the answer would be useful for people who have other ranges of operating temperatures and not just for my scenario.

Comment: If the battery is "hot" then you don't want to push a bunch of current into it, as it will cause further heating.  Heat is a batteries enemy.  So it might stop charging above a certain temp, or slow it down as temps rise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it worth it getting a temperature-sensor for the solar charge-controller?
> Or is it somewhat of a gimmick so they can make some extra money on selling the sensor?

**Spoiler and Short answer**:
*I consider the external Temp. Sensor (in your case 2 large batteries) a luxury with negligible benefits* for life extension of your battery setup.
I recommend firstly investing resources/efforts measuring actual temperatures and currents along a sunny-day, as one single external sensor may be less effective compared to placement improvements and V&I management of your battery group.

**Long-version answer ahead**:
I checked some [RV Solar Charge Controllers](https://thesolarstore.com/rv-solar-charge-controllers-c-40_190.html)  that range from USD 100 to USD 320; some use PWM, others are MPPT; some have internal temperature compensation only (as this [GP-PWM-10-FM](https://thesolarstore.com/go-power-10-amp-flush-mounted-digital-solar-controller-p-2775.html)) while others as [this SSD-25RM](https://thesolarstore.com/manuals/SSD.DAT.Datasheet.01.ENG.pdf) allows dual battery, has internal compensation and accepts an optional External Temp. Sensor, from where I highlighted the following printscreen and I will use as an hypothetical “base-case”:

[image]

**Rated current** (boxed in yellow) = **25A** @ 12V system.
**Internal Temp. comp.** = Yes: **-30mV/°C** from 25°C  (Boxed in green).
**Optional External Temp. Sensor** = YES (boxed in blue).

You also said in comments that:

> In my case a "normal" **temperature range** is probably between **10-30 C** depending on the time of year.
> But sometimes I can experience this entire range in a single day!

Temperature variations of 20°C during the 24h of the day are not rare, but for me, the following questions should be addressed:

1. **Q1**: Is the Battery charged with an initial “high %C” current? Probably not, because you said you have 2  big batteries (not informed how they are connected; assuming here = 1 larger one) and probably even 20A may be smaller than C/10~C/20 for a 200~400Ah setup. If this is the case, Battery(ies) may not heat it up too much and thermal difference (Battery-Controller) is smaller.
2. **Q2**: Does the Battery receive direct solar irradiation or is subject to temperature differences much more intense than the Controller?
   IF YES, *and* IF charging current intense (i > C/5), then internal heat generation may aggravate the situation - and an external sensor may be worth.
3. **Q3**: On the morning, is your Controller indoors and “warmer” than the Battery? If yes, than the temperature compensation is reducing the voltage more than necessary, but this potential undervoltage is *attenuated* along the day, as battery charges and self-heats (a little at i < C/10), while the warmer sunny day provides a higher Ambient temperature. Also, during afternoon, self-heat is reduced as battery may be at 2nd stage (CV mode) and charging current is reduced (then self-heat is also reduced).

**RTS - remote temperature sensor**:
The above controller model cites in the corresponding [RTS page](https://thesolarstore.com/morningstar-remote-temperature-sensor-rts-p-462.html) (USD 40):

> Use of the RTS is recommended whenever the temperature at the **battery** will be more than **5°C (9°F) different** than the temperature at the **controller**.

So, in general, knowing the actual temperature are a must. But you also said *ambient* temperature variations along the year go from 10°C to 30°C. In this case, *probably the difference* in ambient vs indoors (battery vs controller) are +/- 5°C and the internal Temp. Comp. is enough.

---

That all said, I believe your actual temperature differences (Controller x Battery) will less than 5°C~10°C and will be in the conservative side for not gassing/overcharging. This for the assumed colder ambient where you are; but if you were in Texas-hot or Mexico-hotter, it would be the opposite case.

So, Without further information, **I consider the external Temp. Sensor (in your not-so-colder ambient case) a luxury with negligible benefits**. If you have an IR thermometer, it would be worth checking the same three temperatures: (1) “battery spot”, (2) ambient at shadows and (3) “controller place” a few times along a sunny day, just to confirm. And if you could read the charging currents, it would be great too.
The advantage on doing this is to know exactly what is going on, on both sides - indoors and outdoors.

**Dual battery and single external sensor placement**:
Another point is that you have *two* batteries, not knowing if they are very close (or not) and not knowing how they are  electrically connected - so *where* would you install *one* Temp. Sensor?
That is why I believe measuring the actual temperatures and currents are even more necessary than investing beforehand in this additional sensor.

**Bottomline**:
**If your controller already has an internal temperature compensation**, the additional life extension [Bryan](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/622000) answered will not be this case.
I believe the **external sensor will be of marginal improvement**, compared to providing a ventilated area and avoiding overdrain (A) and overdischarging (V).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I don't understand all of the technical terms, but I can see there are a lot of IF's in answering this question. My batteries are very close to the charge controller, and they are inside the motorhome, in shade and somewhat ventilated. As you say, if the charge controller has a temperature sensor already, then it's probably completely irrelevant to put another sensor on the battery. Unfortunately I don't think the controller has a temp sensor built-in, so I guess it might still be useful, right?

Comment: @questiondude, So adding some other “ifs”. If_1 you send the model number & version, or add a photo to your question, I would  try to check about if the internal sensor exists or not. So, if_2 your controller has no internal Temp. sensor And if_3 your motorhome internal temperature varies a lot, Then a Remote Temp. Sensor makes more sense. Otherwise (“Else”) I see this RTS more like a “nice feature” than “makes a difference”.  By the way, how many Watts or Amps you have in your solar panel setup? And how many AH is each extra battery?

Comment: Thanks again! You don't have to go through so much trouble, but if you want to, then the charge controller is a Votronic MPP 250, which has an extensive manual online, but as far as I can tell, it only has internal temperature protection and not a sensor it uses to adjust charging. I already have 2 x 80 Ah GEL batteries. And there will be 2 x 100 W new solar panels.

Comment: @questiondude, I checked your MPP 250 model using this link: https://media1.svb-media.de/media/snr/502391/pdf/manual_en_2014-02-19.pdf. On its PDF page10 of 12 the curves show that your model indeed does *Not* have internal Temp. Comp. - In this case, smaller Temp. variations from 20C nominal are recommended - I would assume +/-10C would imply in -/+ 200mV total, as max deviation limit. Bigger than this, I would rethink to add that single Temp.Sensor - or upgrade the Controller. Meanwhile, one trick would be to change battery model to AGM2 for extreme cold weather, or to GEL for summer hot one

Comment: Thanks for checking! It has been a while and in the meantime I actually asked the company, and they said the same as you: That this particular unit (Votronic MPP 250) only has an internal temp sensor to protect from over-heating and not to regulate the charge voltage. Once again, I appreciate your insights!

Answer (score 3):

While I can’t directly speak to the “worth” of outfitting a specific system with a temp sensor (as I have no experience with solar-battery systems) I can tell you that lead acid batteries are temperature sensitive and both their longevity and their charging are affected by temperature - a smart controller should be better able to charge the battery fully without damage with knowledge of its temperature. In support of this claim I point you towards the excellent articles from Battery Univeristy, starting with their temperature and charging article:

[image: Temp vs charge voltages, batt U]

https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-410-charging-at-high-and-low-temperatures  (Image sourced from article)

> Heat is the worst enemy of batteries, including lead acid. Adding temperature compensation on a lead acid charger to adjust for temperature variations is said to prolong battery life by up to 15 percent. The recommended compensation is a 3mV drop per cell for every degree Celsius rise in temperature. If the float voltage is set to 2.30V/cell at 25°C (77°F), the voltage should read 2.27V/cell at 35°C (95°F). Going colder, the voltage should be 2.33V/cell at 15°C (59°F). These 10°C adjustments represent 30mV change.

Over your temperature range you could see a reduction in recommended charging voltage of 60mV/cell, for a total of **0.36V** on a conventional "12V" Lead acid battery - not a trivial difference.

Do read up on all they have to offer on lead acid battery technology.

Comment: Thanks! From the plot there seems to be a negligible difference for the 10-30 C temperature range. But the article you link to says the following: **"Heat is the worst enemy of batteries, including lead acid. Adding temperature compensation on a lead acid charger to adjust for temperature variations is said to prolong battery life by up to 15 percent."** Please update your answer with some of the most relevant quotes from that very long article, including the quote I gave here, then I will mark it as the "correct" answer. Thanks!

Comment: @questiondude added that quote and a bit of analysis, thanks for the tip.

Comment: In the meantime someone else posted a very long and detailed answer, so I thought that ought to be marked as the "correct" answer. Unfortunately I cannot mark two answers as "correct", so I just upvoted yours. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: @questiondude I concur, that answer speaks directly to the “worth it” aspect of the question.